# Problema al leer archivo txt con java

Tags: java

Tengo un paquete Configuración donde tengo una clase Config.java y un archivo config.txt que quiero leer.

Config.java

```
public class Config {


public String obtenerConfig(){

    String texto = "";

    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("config.txt"));
        String temp = "";
        String bfRead;
        while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null)
            temp = temp + bfRead;

        texto = temp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Pero al ejecutarlo me dice que no ha podido encontrar el archivo.

Si pongo la ruta completa ("C:\Documentos\blabla\config.txt") en vez de ("config.txt") si funciona, pero no me sirve de esa forma.

Aca les paso una foto para que vean que estan los dos en el mismo lugar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: ¿y estas completamente seguro que el archivo config.txt el programa se encuentra en el mismo sitio que Config.java?

Comment: si si, están los dos en el mismo paquete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar getResourceAsStream() y en tu código quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
public String obtenerConfig(){

    String texto = "";
    String temp = "";

    try {

        InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("config.txt");
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, "utf-8");         
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(reader);


        String bfRead;
        while((bfRead = bf.readLine()) != null)
            temp = temp + bfRead;

        texto = temp;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return texto;
}
```

Comment: Funcionó, gracias!

Comment: Cuando lo intento me sale null

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas en este caso es un cargador de clases, el cual permite a una aplicación acceder a los repositorios de clases y recursos disponibles. Pero no cualquier cargador de clases, porque hay muchos en el entorno de ejecución, sino aquel que **cargó** la clase `Config`.

❍ Si estás utilizando **Java** **5**/**6**, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public String obtenerConfig() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = Config.class.getResourceAsStream("config.txt");
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
        for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
            sb.append(line);
            sb.append('\n');
        }
        reader.close();
        streamReader.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

❍ Si estás usando **Java** **7**/**8**, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public String obtenerConfig() {
    String content = null;
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getResource("config.txt").toURI());
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
        content = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return content;
}
```