# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": CreateProcess error=2 al ejecutar un CMD en JAVA

Tags: java, cmd

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa y desde hace un rato estoy teniendo este error (antes no me pasaba y alguna vez no me pasa)

Esto es lo que ejecuta

```
String comando = "cmd.exe /c echo n | .\\simulador.exe " +home+ "sht.txt "+away+"sht.txt";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando);
```

Y este el error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": CreateProcess error=2
```

Adjunto tambien el error completo

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe": CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:451)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:348)
    at autoesms.AutoESMS.simularPartido(AutoESMS.java:138)
    at autoesms.AutoESMS.rellenarJornadas(AutoESMS.java:123)
    at autoesms.AutoESMS.main(AutoESMS.java:49)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:444)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:140)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

¿alguien entiende que pasa?

Comment: Puede ser que al lanzarlo así no tenga en cuenta el PATH y necesite que le indiques la ruta completa

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema al leer archivo txt con java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/37878/problema-al-leer-archivo-txt-con-java)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba especificar la ruta completa del cmd `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` en caso no te este reconociendo el comando en el sistema, verifica si has modificado alguna variable del PATH porque este comando debería de ser accesible como describes el inicio.